# Generate facebook/ linkedin website preview image screenshot with Nuxt / VueJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

We're generating about 5,000 pages with `nuxt generate`. Many of those is heavily shared on Facebook and LinkedIn.

What's the best way to pre-generate the preview screenshots of those 5,000 pages? Is there a script or NPM package for just that?

In essence, it should pre-generate the screenshots filling (`nuxt.config.js`):

```js
{ property: 'og:image', content: 'https://example.com/social/page-4999-screenshot.png' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a Node script that launches Nuxt and then runs [Puppeteer to grab a screenshot](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions).

For example, the following script could be run with `node ./screenshot.js 8081`. It could be modified to run iteratively for all 5000 pages.

```js
// screenshot.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const nuxt = require('@nuxt/cli');

(async () => {
  const port = process.argv[3]

  try {
    await nuxt.run(['generate'])
    await nuxt.run(['dev', '--port', port])
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(2)
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`http://localhost:${port}`)
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' })
  } finally {
    await browser.close()
  }

  // force exit as Nuxt server is still listening...
  process.exit(0)
})()
```